# how to use model in django view

Tags: python, django, database, view, model

I want to use my model parameter for the API query parameter in Django View. How can I use this?
Anyone can give me suggestions.
Here curd is my model name. and consumer_type is the required query parameter

```
  from .models import curd
  for consumer_type in curd:
  response = requests.get("http://localhost:8280?ConsumerID="+consumer_type)
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! Please share the code of the view you are using. Probably urls also.

Comment: Did you do the Django tutorial? You will learn how to do queries with your models there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the view, you can access the `GET` request like so:

```
if request.method == "GET":
    print(request.GET)
```

Then you could filter with:

```
cons_id = request.GET.get('ConsumerID', None)
if cons_id is None:
    raise Http404
else:
    mymodel = MyModel.objects.filter(...)
```